# Trying to pass a Java variable into a sql string

Tags: java, sql, database

I've had a look around on the web but can't seem to find a definite answer to my question.

Basically, I have a database and table that are successfully working. Now I want to read each line from my table one by one and store the result into a array and I am trying to use a for loop to be more professional rather then using repetition.

I have this  code

```
for (int i=1; i<=8; i++)
{
    String query = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = i";
    Rs = St.executeQuery(query);
    COL1Title[i] = Rs.getString("CO1Name");
    COL2Age[i] = Rs.getString("CO2Rating");
}
```

The for loop is in a try catch statement and it's complaining with the error "Unknown column 'i' in 'where clause'"

Im guessing there's a certain way for how variable i is to be inserted in the the query.

I should point out ID is a column that has the auto increment feature added on and is primary key if that helps

Could anyone help me out here?

Comment: You can simply concatenate ```i```. As in ```String query = "Select * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = " +i ```.

Comment: @user2864740 `i` is an `int`. There is no worry about sql injection.

Comment: Maybe you should read *many* lines at once? `WHERE ID >= 1 AND ID <= 8` and loop the result-set? Use *placeholders* to fill in the query data.

Comment: Added the improvement and now have a new error of "Error is: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set"

Comment: @user2864740 Please, enlighten me!

Comment: @Bobski You must call `rs.next()` once first before trying to access any columns (of the first record). The result set pointer starts *before* the first record. This is so it can be used like so: `while(rs.next()) { /* process record */ }`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, we can simplify the task be executing a single query. Note the addition of the range limit and the ORDER BY - without an ORDER BY the results have an unspecified order!

```
PreparedStatement stmt = "Select ID, CO1Name, CO2Rating"
    + " FROM Table1"
    + " WHERE ID >= ? AND ID <= ?"
    + " ORDER BY ID";
```

And bind in placeholders (unless there is good reason otherwise, *always* use placeholders when injecting data into a query). The values could have been hard-coded above in this case, just as they are hard-coded in the for-loop, but the binding is shown here for future reference:

```
stmt.setInt(1, 1);
stmt.setInt(2, 8);
```

Then execute the query:

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery();
```

And iterate the results. Note that `rs.next()` must be invoke once before any column is read (the cursor starts *before* any records) and, in this case, it makes it easy to handle a bunch of results.

```
while (rs.next()) {
   int id = rs.getInt("ID");
   String title = rs.getString("CO1Name");
   String name = rs.getString("CO2Rating");
   // do stuff with this record
}
```

Note that even though the ORDER BY guarantees that the results are iterated in order of ID, assuming a database cardinality rule ensures each result has a unique ID, there may be 0 to 8 records returned - that is, non-existent records may need to be detected/handled separately.

Also (but not shown), make sure to cleanup (`close`) the ResultSet when done: use a try/finally or try-with-resources construct.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question but what do the integers mean inside getString

Comment: @Bobski They refer to the column index (1 is the first column). Alternatively, and perhaps better, the column name could be used. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int) - actually, I'll change it back :)\

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass i in string as integer, Replace line by:

```
String query = String.format("Select * FROM Table1 WHERE ID = %d",i);
```

Comment: I downvoted for advocating the use of manual SQL string building. Don't do this without *very good reason*. And definitely *do not suggest it* without explaining why it should only be used with very good reason!

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with this manual SQL building. If you are thinking SQL injection, I'd like to see you try, with integers defined locally withing a loop.

Comment: but this answer solves the op's problem hence useful.

Comment: I suggest you leave a comment before downvoting for reasons that do not apply in the given situation. I agree that SQL injection should be explained but you can present it in a milder tone.

Comment: @user3020494 No. It just propagates bad practices to individuals who don't know better (e.g. are still learning).

Comment: Right the error of "Error is: java.sql.SQLException: Before start of result set" is to do with something else I'm guessing? Thats shown after I added the above statement in

Comment: @user2864740 So, you are basically saying that the answer is correct. You just think that you would not approve the use of concatenation of strings here. Instead of downvoting, you should have shared your remarks to make the answer better or contribute your own answer. The answer is correct.

Comment: This thread is ridiculous.  If someone doesn't agree with the answer given by user3020494  then they simply need to provide a better answer as an option.  It is absolutely NOT TRUE that an answer like this means that it propagates bad practice.  What propagates bad practice is a lack of good answers by people who know.

Comment: @EdwinDalorzo No, I am not. I am saying it is wrong, and that I am ashamed that it is receiving positive votes. I would reject this code/suggestion in a code-review and I believe that similar standards should exist for SO.